# Email to Case in Lightning stores attachments as attachments not files

Tags: lightning, email2case

If I add an attachment to a case, SF will create it as a file.

But when email to case creates the case and adds the attachment, it is still an attachment.

How to get email to case to attach the email attachments as SF files and not SF attachments?

Thanks.

Edit: this doesn't work:

```
trigger EmailTrigger on EmailMessage (after insert) {
   //gather case from which emailMessages had an attachment
    Set<Id> setParentId = new Set<Id>();
     for(EmailMessage em: Trigger.new)
     {
         if(em.HasAttachment)
         {
           setParentId.add(em.ParentId);
         }
     }
    //new whatever this is; needed to make contentDocument
ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion();
    //attempt to gather the case that was created via email2case
     List<Case> lstCases = [select Id  from Case where Id IN :setParentId];
    Set<id> setCaseIds = new Set<Id>();
    //write down all the ids
    For(Case c : lstCases)
     {
         setCaseIds.add(c.Id);
      }
    //get the attachment(s) from the case
     List<Attachment> lstAttachments = [select Id, Name, Body from 
 Attachment where ParentId IN :setCaseIds];
     For(Case c : lstCases)
     {
            //create a file and relate it to the case
         for(Attachment a : lstAttachments){

         cv.VersionData = a.Body;
         cv.Title = a.name;
         cv.ContentDocumentId = c.id;
             }
     }

 insert cv;
```

}